# Running JNI program in ubuntu

Tags: java-native-interface, runtime-error

I am running my first program in ubuntu.

But there was an error when I tried to run it:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no foo in  java.library.path
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1681)
  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
  at JNIFoo.<clinit>(JNIFoo.java:6)
  Could not find the main class: JNIFoo. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no foo in  java.library.path
```

Fix your library path and try again.

Answer (score 2):

These lines taken from [Getting Stated JNI from SUN site](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/start.html)

> Make sure that the native library resides in one of the directories in
>   the native library path.  If you are running on a Solaris system, the
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable is used to  define  the native
>   library path. Make sure that it includes the name of the directory
>   that  contains the libHelloWorld.so file. If the libHelloWorld.so file
>   is in the current directory, you can issue the following two commands
>   in the standard shell (sh) or KornShell (ksh) to  set up  the
>   `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable properly:
>
> ```
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> ```